# Bash: Using '\b' makes strings not equal?

Tags: bash

I'm a bit perplexed as to why this doesn't return true...

```
if [ "$(echo -e 'b\bg')" == "g" ]; then
    echo "true"
else
    echo "false"
fi
```

Even without `'` (instead a `\"`) it doesn't work.

Running it in a console does:

```
~$ echo -e 'b\bg'       
   g
```

So, does `g` not equal `g` in this senario or something?

Comment: `'b\bg'` and `'g'` are different strings that happen to display the same when you print them on your terminal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\b` does not remove the preceding character from the string; when displayed, it causes the cursor to move backwards one position, resulting in the preceding character being overwritten by the following character. `b\bg` is still a 3-character string that will not match any one-character string, even if they look identical when displayed. (For that matter, it is not guaranteed that a terminal will treat `\b` as moving the cursor back; it might simply display an unprintable character glyph in its place, e.g. `b?g`.)